# Can a TensorFlow Lite model keep optimizing inside the app? (Code-less Question)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

In the documentation of the platform they specify:

> TensorFlow Lite does not currently support on-device training

So do I have to constantly update the model, and then update the app's model, because it won't optimize results on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to update the model and then update the app's model if you want to improve the results further after implementing the initial model.

Answer (score 0):

There is some support for on-device personalization using TensorFlow Lite. Please see:

- [Example on-device model personalization with TensorFlow Lite (blog)](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/12/example-on-device-model-personalization.html)
- [Official example project on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/model_personalization)